# Objective-C - Making an image link

Tags: objective-c, image, url, hyperlink

The thing is that I'm rather new to Objective-C and have been reading about it now for a few days online. I started to create a simple iOS application but I didn't find anything about this when I Googled it.

Now I want to create a link that is not plain text, but an image.
If this is incomprehensible, then this is how I would do it in HTML:

```
<a href="URL"><img src="IMAGE.png"/></a>
```

So far in my ViewController.h, I have:

```
-(IBAction)link;
```

And in my ViewController.m, I have:

```
-(IBAction)link {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];
}
```

How would I link this URL to an image? 
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to do that. You can add a button on top of the image and make the button send actions to the view controller, or you can link it to `-(IBAction)link;` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `UIButton` in IB/Storyboard to your view. 
Make that button of the same size that your image is. 
Assing the image as the buttons image or background image. 
Connect the `touch up inside` event with the `IBAction link`.

Or do you want to do that programmatically?